# How to automatically align python variable assignment lines in vim

Tags: vim

I would like to automatically align lines of python variable assignments in vim.

For example I would like to change this:

```
a = 1
banana = 2
```

into this

```
a      = 1
banana = 2
```

automatically in vim.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd like to mention that PEP 8 (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) explicitly discourages this kind of formatting.

Comment: More importantly, is there a reason for doing this?  What's all the extra whitespace for?

Comment: saua, noted thanks!
S.Lott, it's mostly because it is easier for me to read.

Comment: How so?  Seriously.  What's the benefit?  Don't you find that things get confused with the lines of code above or below?

Comment: I agree with Mr. Eden here. I even indent "from x import y"'s! It reads better and looks neater, IMHO.

Comment: @PaulD.Eden I also noticed the style guide discouraging this. What is your take on it now, years later?

Comment: I agree with @Eden and co. Further, the discouragement in PEP 8 is only in the "Pet Peeves" section with no further rationale. So anyone with an actual rationale ("it's more readable for me") should go for it, and cite "hobgoblins" and PEP 20 :-).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are probably looking for the Align plugin for vim:

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294

Once installed, you simply select the text you want to align (Shift V) and type:

:Align =

This will align the text based on the = character, so you can use anything you want really.

Comment: ⁺¹ for the mention that it is a plugin. I am found the command in a vim wiki, and was wondering why VIM concerns this command wrong. Now I decided to google more, and found here that this is a plugin. Btw, Emacs has the functional out of the box :Ь

Answer (score 1):

The [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) plugin does this and much more.

Answer (score 1):

Try the [align plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294).

It's described [here](http://linux.byexamples.com/archives/153/vim-tip-1-align/)...

Answer (score 0):

this will do the work :

```
vap

:!column -t
```